# Capitalisation of a sacred object

Tags: grammar, nouns, punctuation, capitalization

I'm working in an Indigenous Australian context in which particular sacred trees and animals are capitalised. I'm aware that the specific name of the tree, for example, needs to be capitalised but would I capitalise the word 'tree' in the following example?

> 'The Wattle **tree** is sacred to us'

Or

> 'The Wattle **Tree** is sacred to us'

Thanks

Comment: I would say that it depends on whether you are referring to the tree as a species, or to a particular tree. A special, individual tree would have its name capitalised, a species (like 'oak tree') wouldn't.

Comment: The capitalisation is because it's an article title, but it might be relevant that [*Aboriginal Peoples Did Not have Written Languages*](https://www.ictinc.ca/blog/aboriginal-peoples-did-not-have-written-languages#:~:text=Aboriginal%20Peoples%20did%20not%20have%20written%20languages%20although%20many%20of,to%20pass%20down%20their%20history.) - so arguably the Indigenous Australians themselves don't get a vote on this one!

Comment: @KateBunting: I'm not sure what context you'd be talking about where "the wattle tree" refers to a *specific* tree, and therefore might justify being capitalised. Consider, say, *The oak tree in this valley is sacred to the local Druids*. Who would capitalise that?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I was thinking of individual, named trees, such as the [Major Oak](https://www.visitsherwood.co.uk/explore-the-forest/the-major-oak/) in Sherwood Forest.

Comment: In Terry Gustavson's review ([EnidBlytonSociety](https://www.enidblytonsociety.co.uk/book-details.php?id=216)) of the eponymous work of childrens (ooh, no apostrophe) fiction, he uses 'Magic Faraway Tree' and 'Faraway Tree' without exception throughout his article. This is equivalent to adopting a compound (whether 2- or 3-orthographic words) proper name and conferring the usual respect (it probably also subtly involves anthropomorphism). A snag here is that 'wattle tree' is used by non-initiates in the usual way, like 'pine tree' or 'ash tree'. I'd say (1) ask those who might ...

Comment: have a preference in the domain involved (scientists would **demand** Acacia pravissima for Oven's wattle (which apparently _isn't_ a wattle!) for instance. Does non-capitalisation offend some people? Why not comply, locally?

Comment: Closely related: [Is there a trend toward not capitalizing the word _Bible_?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/523159/is-there-a-trend-toward-not-capitalizing-the-word-bible/523162#523162) // [Should I capitalize 'bible' in 'the Christian Bible'? 'the Discordian Bible'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/231518/should-i-capitalize-bible-in-the-christian-bible-the-discordian-bible/239844#239844)

Comment: I am voting to close this as it is giving rise to opinions and I seriously suggest that you ask the Aboriginals. To do otherwise would be a grave mistake. There seems little point in asking someone not of the religion/belief system what form a certain word or phrase - significant to that religion - should take. This is a cultural matter, not a matter of language. There are several "Aboriginal Councils", e.g. https://alc.org.au/ahims/, I assume that any one of them could provide an answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

According to most Style Guides, Proper Nouns will have Capitalizations through out, except maybe for words like "the", "a" or "of".

So both words in your example should be Capitalized :

> 'The Wattle Tree is sacred to us'

Quick Reference:
https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/common-vs-proper-nouns/

More Examples, taking these as made-up names of movies or novels :

> Harry Potter and the Chamber of Capital Letters
> Helena of Troy
> Queen in a Cage

UPDATE :

[[ I am not sure what to make of this situation; The answer by @FumbleFingers goes against my answer, but still the google ngram used in that answer is in support of my answer ! ]]

Using this query in Google Books Ngram Viewer ....

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+Wattle+tree%2Cthe+wattle+tree%2Cthe+Wattle+Tree&year_start=1920&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20Wattle%20tree%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20wattle%20tree%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20Wattle%20Tree%3B%2Cc0

.... I get this Statistic:

[image: Green line moving UP !]

Even though I am not sure what to make of this, I think : (1) **"the Wattle Tree"** is currently used, and is increasing in usage ; (2) "the Wattle tree" is not common ; & (3) "the wattle tree" is very common in general, but may not be suitable in the "Sacred Sense" required by OP.

Comment: This might be true if they're talking about a specific instance of wattle trees, but if they're talking about wattle trees in general, it wouldn't be.

Comment: I just searched Google Books for ["tree is sacred to"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tree+is+sacred+to%22). The first page of 10 results included *... the **hawthorn tree** is sacred to many people...  the **bodhi tree** is sacred to Buddhists...  The **silk-cotton tree** is sacred to the Ngombe,,,  The **ash tree** is sacred to the Celts.* But I didn't see ***any*** instances featuring capitalisation. If it's just a type of tree (as opposed to a proper noun like [*the **Yggdrasil** tree*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+Yggdrasil+tree%22), I wouldn't capitalise.

Comment: (Capitalisation of books and movies is irrelevant here, because they're ***titles***, not "nouns referring to entities", so they get capitalised the same way as newspaper headlines.)

Comment: Requesting your thoughts on my update , @FumbleFingers

Comment: My thoughts are in my own answer. Your wattle trees may not be as familiar to us as oaks sacred to Druids, or cow to Hindus, but that's no reason to put them on a higher pedestal by capitalising.

Comment: I was asking you about "WT" being **at a high rate** of usage, instead of the non-existent usage claimed in your answer ; Only "Wt" is at a very low rate of usage. These things support my answer : **Do not use "Wt" ; Can use "WT" in context**. Currently, the only thing I can update in my answer is : In general usage, "wt" is more common. @FumbleFingers

Comment: I certainly never claimed capitalised ***The Wattle Tree*** was "non-existent" - I just said ***I*** wouldn't do it, and ***nor do most other writers***. And both our charts clearly show that most written instances *aren't* capitalised. I also backed up my general point with clear evidence that *The **cow** is sacred to Hindus* is almost never capitalised - but there's not a single instance of *The wattle tree is sacred [to anyone]* in Google Books, so I couldn't address that usage specifically.

Comment: Oh ok, I got it. I would like to change my Previous Comment to replace "claimed" with "indirectly implied", because in both your Charts, there is no "WT" ! Moving on : In my Chart, there is 1 Instance of "WT" for every 2 Instances of "wt", which is not negligible, indicating a common variant in usage. Similarly, there is 1 Instance of "Humour" for every 2 Instances of "Humor" indicating that one is a common variant of the other. @FumbleFingers

Comment: Okay, okay! I can't explain why I didn't happen to include "WT" in my charts - all I can say is I obviously had to include "**The**" or "**the**" before **wt / Wt / WT / w-t / W-t / W-T**, so that's 12 permutations. And "WT" only manages to account for 30% of usages in the past decade or two - any more than 20 years ago, that was an *extremely* rare orthography. Do you want to promote a "new" usage, or report on what most people have done in the past? Again with the "negligible" implications though. I never said anything like that before this very comment.

Answer (score 2):

I interpret the OP's question to be:

> Taking it as given that *Wattle* is capitalised in this context, should *tree* in the phrase *Wattle tree* be capitalised as well?

That is, I set aside the question, raised in another answer, about the capitalisation of *Wattle*, and simply assume that, in this context, it should be capitalised.

The question is similar to [the question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/585976) that was asked before about the capitalisation of, for example, *integral* in *Riemann integral*. In all these cases we have a phrase that contains a word that is definitely a proper name, and a word that, in other contexts, functions as a common noun. The question is then whether to treat the latter in such cases as a common noun or a part of a two-word proper name.

There is no general answer to such questions; it is a matter of conventions that differ from one field to another. Consider, for example the geographic names, such as the *Atlantic Ocean*. In these cases, it is a well established convention to treat the whole two-word phrase as the proper name of the ocean, and to consequently capitalise both words. Somebody could reason that this is simply an ocean, one among several, that is distinguished from the others by the name *Atlantic*, and that *ocean* should therefore not be capitalised. There would be nothing wrong with this reasoning considered in the abstract (after all, that's precisely what is done in, say, French), it's just that the universally accepted convention among English speakers is to the contrary. The conventions, however, go the other way with respect to *Riemann integral*, *Euler's number* and suchlike. One could argue that *Euler's number* is the proper name of that number and that consequently both words in that phrase ought to be capitalised; there would be nothing in principle wrong about that argument; it's just that, as a matter of convention, it hasn't been generally embraced.

So, the answer to the OP is: there is no general rule of the language that determines whether to capitalise *tree* in *Wattle tree* (again, taking it as given that *Wattle* is to be capitalised). It is a matter of convention in the relevant field. If it is an established practice among the respectable writers in the field to capitalise it, it would be wise to go along; if not, not.

Comment: +1 , I "Interpreted" it the same way in my answer, that is, I took that as a Proper Noun and hence, I said that both words should be Capitalized, using the "rules" for Proper Nouns.

Comment: ... So POB; the 'how long is the proper noun' question has been dealt with per se.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, what exactly is 'POB' here: **(1)** that this is a matter of field-specific conventions, or **(2)** which convention would be better to adopt here? The answer says nothing about the latter (which could indeed be argued to be a matter of opinion); the former is not itself a matter of opinion (it is either true or false; if you believe that it is false, you should say so, and post what you regard as the correct answer). See [this meta-question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15318).

Comment: I see no inherent conflict between this and my own answer. All things being equal, I personally *wouldn't* capitalise "wattle", so the issue of whether or not to capitalise "tree" simply wouldn't arise. But all things *aren't* equal if we assume as a given that "Wattle" ***will*** be capitalised, in which case I personally probably *would* capitalise "Tree" as well. But that's a stylistic choice which most people apparently *don't* make in such contexts...

Comment: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sat+under+the+Bodhi+Tree%2Csat+under+the+Bodhi+tree%2Csat+under+the+bodhi+tree&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csat%20under%20the%20Bodhi%20Tree%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csat%20under%20the%20Bodhi%20tree%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csat%20under%20the%20bodhi%20tree%3B%2Cc0) for ***sat under the Bodhi tree*** - which will almost always be a reference to Buddha sitting there gaining enlightenment, so that's obviously another "sacred" context (where "Tree" usually *isn't* capitalised, but ***I*** would do that).

Comment: The ellipsis indicates a follow-on from the previous comment. 'I "Interpreted" it the same way in my answer, that is, I took that as a Proper Noun and hence ...'; Prem states that he made a judgement call.  Whether or not to capitalise 'tree' is a matter of local custom, perhaps just linguistic happenstance, perhaps related to religious preference (as with Bible/bible). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_individual_trees) lists << Baikushev's pine >> and << Brian Boru's Oak >>, << Washington tree >> and << Survivor Tree >> among named individual specimens.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I didn't quite see it in your answer that 'But all things aren't equal if we assume as a given that "Wattle" will be capitalised, in which case I personally probably would capitalise "Tree" as well.' Adding that to the answer would be a significant modification.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't even capitalise ***wattle***, let alone ***tree***. [Nor do most other writers...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20Wattle%20tree%2Cthe%20wattle%20tree%2Cthe%20Wattle-tree%2Cthe%20wattle-tree&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10)

[image]

Being case-sensitive, the above chart misses sentences *starting* with ***The***, so for good measure here are those too...

[image]

Of course, this tree is "important" (but not necessarily "sacred") to many "non-indigenous" Australians too, given that apparently [***The wattle tree is the national emblem of Australia***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wattle%20tree%20is%20the%20national%20emblem%20of%20Australia%22)

I would also point out that almost no-one ever capitalises [***The cow is sacred to Hindus.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the%20cow%20is%20sacred%20to%20Hindus%22) That just seems more "natural" to most Anglophones because we're more familiar with ***cows*** than ***wattle-trees***.

Comment: +1 for the carefully limited claim in the first line. Capitalizing one or both words remains an available rhetorical choice, at least in dual-case writing systems. Similar (and fraught)  choices determine whether a writer or publication renders racial designations as "black and white" or "Black and white" or "Black and White."

Comment: With all due respect, I don't think that this answer is sufficiently attentive to the fact that OP is 'working in an Indigenous Australian context' in which these trees are regarded as sacred. Capitalising their names fits well the general rules of the language if they function as proper names in this context, even if they are common nouns in other contexts. Pronouncing a judgment on whether they can be regarded as proper names would require a more extensive discussion of the conceptualisation of the trees in the relevant cultural/religious framework.

Comment: @jsw29: I don't see how "an Indigenous Australian context" is any different to the context of my example cow being sacred to Hindus. Actually, I think capitalising my Cow or OP's Wattle Tree is really just a kind of "poetic flourish" optional stylistic choice - like Blake's capitalised [***Tyger, Tyger** , burning bright, In the forests of the night.*](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/43687/the-tyger) (Except I personally ***like*** Tygers, cows, and wattle trees, not the other way around! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you are right that sacredness by itself in not a sufficient reason for capitalising the word. To determine whether *wattle* functions as a proper name here, one would need to  to know more than just that wattle trees are regarded a sacred; one would need to understand the nature of their sacredness. Forming an opinion on whether the Indigenous Australian and Hindu contexts are different in this respect would require a discussion of their respective ways of conceptualising these creatures; I am not arguing the matter either way.